# Angurar.js set correct URL of the services with nested resource

Tags: angularjs, api, rest, angular-resource

I've created a nested resources in my backend.
Eg. /resource/:id_resource/subResource/:id_subResource
I'm new in angular.js and I'm trying to find the best way to do this.
I've used the *services* and **angular-resource** components and I need to understand how to pass the first part of the URL with the /resource/:id_resource/ in this correct format (not as normal parameter).

```
projectsServices.factory('SubResource', ['$resource','$location',
    function($resource, $location){
        return $resource($location.$$path , {}, {
            query: {method:'GET', params:{}, isArray:true}
        });
    }]);
```

this is basically tied to the route

```
.when('/**resource**/:id_resource/**subResource**/:id_subResource', {
                templateUrl: '/partials/[...].html',
                controller: '[...]DetailsCtrl'
```

so the URL requested to the API is strictly tied with $location.
It works but I think is not the best way to do it.
Any thoughts about it?

Comment: use angular-ui-router for dynamic routing: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: This is a pretty good & quick tutorial - https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-using-resource-for-data-models

Comment: Thanks Dylan!, Thanks Connor :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for is just `$routeParams` - something like.

```
factory('SubResource', ['$resource', function ($resource){
   return $resource('/api/:param_one/sub/:param_two', 
      {param_one:"@_id", param_two: "@id_sub"},
   {
    update: {
       method: 'PUT'
    }
 });
 }]);
```

Then in your controller

```
app.controller('Ctrl',function($scope, $routeParams  
...

SubResource.get({
  param_one: $routeParams.thingId, 
  param_two: $routeParams.thingId_sub
  },
  function(data){...});
```

This pull the params from your route

```
.when('thing/:thingId/sub/:thingId_sub', {
```

And after, if your query is your model you can just update if the parameters @ matches.

```
SubResource.$update(function(res) {
   $location.path('SubResource/' + res._id);
});
```